# Facebook "Send to Messenger" button not showing locally

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I am trying to use the Send to Messenger plugin and can't use it locally. I check some questions about hidden button and all of them was resolved after deploy.

But I need to use this plugin locally - need to get auth-callback from local .html(from chrome-extension options) 
Span of "Send to Messenger plugin button" hidden if it calls locally, I try to `overflow: visible` - it works fine(but I think it is wrong). Can somebody guide how to use this button?

And if I checked once this button - just try to use it - it doesn't shows again with checked state is it right? or I break something?

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br> hello! <br>
<div class="fb-send-to-messenger"  
     messenger_app_id="APP-ID" 
     page_id="PAGE_ID" 
     data-ref="PASS_THROUGH_PARAM" 
     color="white" 
     size="large"></div>
<script src="wat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

wat.js

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
    appId      : '1746289228945988',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.7'
   });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: @wOxxOm course, add some snippets

Comment: Yes plugin loaded, but if page shows locally plugin hidden, only overflow:visible !important; shows it. Yes, added: "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'".  Yes it initialize succesfully, I even try to FB.ui and open dialog it works fine